# Appending DataFrame to matching cells in Google Sheets

Tags: python, gspread

I am inputting data from a Google Sheet (using gspread), cleaning it, running it through a model to get a QScore from the model.

I want to then write this QScore BACK to the Google Sheet in a column called Qscore, but it needs to match up with the ID Number that the Q Score was generated for.

My current output is

```
     ID qscore
0   A-1 0.317931
1   G-3 0.106749
2   G-4 0.392376
3   G-A 0.179825
4   G-B 0.428286
```

Again, my goal is to find the existing row that has A-1, and then append the Qscore to that same row under the qscore column. (And then for all other ID numbers that have generated a qscore.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you have a specific issue? This is quite broad/vague.

Comment: I apologize for it being broad.

My workflow is essentially (including the end goal)

Pull data from google sheets —> Filter it for data with an empty qscore column —> Clean remaining data to run through model —> run it through the model to generate a qscore —> put generated qscores back onto the original google sheet

But qscores are specific to an ID #, so thats why I need to make sure I match them properly.

Comment: Okay, so what ideas do you have for this?